# Element of structure pointer points to another address in C

Tags: c, pointers, structure, microchip, xc16

I have a structure in C for a motor control application, the structure have the element for a PID.  I created 2 variables with that structure and 2 pointers pointing to those variable.  My application is on a microcontroller so I have an other register that is quite important for the PID to work, that is the encoder count.
So I would like to have my pointers pointing to their respective PID variable but I would like to have the element "Encoder" pointing to the encoder register of the microcontroller.  So that when I access the pointer I can get the encoder position directly.

```
typedef struct{
   int Error;
   int DeadBand;
   int SetPoint;
   int Encoder;
   .
   .
   .
   double Integral;
   double Derivative;
   double Kp;
   double Ki;
   double Kd;
   float Position;
   bool Done;
}Upid;

Upid PID1, PID2, *pPID1, *pPID2;
pPID1 = &PID1;
pPID2 = &PID2;
pPID1->Encoder = &POS1CNTL;
pPID2->Encoder = &POS2CNTL;
```

I didn't try the code above because I 100% it will not work like I want.  Dereferencing the element Encoder and assigning the address of the encoder position register will just put the address number in the Encoder element.  It is only there to show a little what I want to accomplish.  But I don't know how to do that.

After I want to be able to call functions without the need to include the Encoder count in the function itself.

Now I do something like this:

```
void MovePosition(Upid* PID, int Acceleration, int MaxVelocity, int StartPosition, int EndPosition)
{
    PID->Acceleration = Acceleration;
    PID->MaxVelocity = MaxVelocity;
    PID->Position = PID->StartPos = StartPosition;
    PID->EndPos = EndPosition;
    PID->DeceleratonStarted = false;
    PID->VelocityMode = false;
    PID->Step = 0;
    PID->Done = false;
}
```

When I call this function, I always put the current encoder count (the value of the encoder count register of the microcontroller) in the StartPosition.

I would like to do something like this:

```
void MovePosition(Upid* PID, int Acceleration, int MaxVelocity, int EndPosition)
{
    PID->Acceleration = Acceleration;
    PID->MaxVelocity = MaxVelocity;
    PID->Position = PID->StartPos = PID->Encoder;
    PID->EndPos = EndPosition;
    PID->DeceleratonStarted = false;
    PID->VelocityMode = false;
    PID->Step = 0;
    PID->Done = false;
}
```

Where everything points to the PID1 or PID2 variable but the element Encoder points to the microcontroller's Encoder count register.

How would I be able to do something like this?
Thank you.

Edit:
I use a microchip microcontroller with the XC16 compiler.
I use POS1CNTL like a normal variable:
I can read it like:  A = POS1CNTL;
Or I can write a value to it like: POS1CNTL = 30;

POS1CNTL is defined a follow:
#define POS1CNTL POS1CNTL
extern volatile uint16_t  POS1CNTL **attribute**((**sfr**));

Comment: Can you modify the structure? (To turn the `Encoder` member into an actual pointer)

Comment: Just change `int Encoder` to `int* Encoder`...??

Comment: I sure can change the Encoder element to a pointer.  How would I do the rest to point to the register if the microcontroller?  If I just change it to a pointer and leave the code like that:

    pPID1 = &PID1;
    pPID2 = &PID2;
    pPID1->Encoder = &POS1CNTL;
    pPID2->Encoder = &POS2CNTL;

I get assignment warning
assignment discards qualifiers from pointer target type

Comment: Then what *is* `POS1CNTL`? Can you find its declaration? Can you [edit] your question to show it?

Comment: POS1CNTL is the encoder register.  It is part of the microcontroller's compiler I guess...  I use that to get encoder values.

Comment: It's probably declared in a system header file, can you search them? And if you use e.g. `POS1CNTL`  directly, *how* do you use it?'

Comment: And what MCU are you using? What compiler? Please [edit] your question to include that information. It can help you find users that actually know that environment and the declaration of `POS1CNTL` and can help you better.

Comment: I edited the question to answer your comments.

Comment: Since your encoder count is in a special peripheral register, it may or may not be possible to access it through a normal pointer. Can't say for sure until you show us at least the full definition (something which includes a memory address/offset). That said, `pPID1->Encoder = &POS1CNTL;`, with maybe a typecast, seems to be the only way to get what you want. What error do you get with it?

Comment: Regarding the "assignment discards qualifiers" warning, that's probably because of the `volatile` qualifier. If you declare `Encoder` as `volatile uint16_t *Encoder;` do you still get a warning? Then if you use e.g. `*pPID1->Encoder` do you get the same value as when using `POS1CNTL` directly? How about when you write to `*pPID1->Encoder`, does it set the correct value?

Comment: It works with what you suggested  Some programmer dude  
Thanks